# C++ Builder Linker error file IDRESOURCESTRINGSCORE.OBJ

Tags: c++builder

I have just added some pascal files to c++ Builder project and now get the following linker error

[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'IDRESOURCESTRINGSCORE.OBJ'

I searched entire drive and this object file does not exist anywhere on the PC so I know it's not just an include directory which is wrong. Can anyone tell me what this object file is associated with so I can get the link to work?

Comment: `IdResourceStringsCore` is a unit in the Indy 10 library, in its Core package.  It is a `.pas` file, it gets compiled into a `.dcu` file, not an `.obj` file.  But the linker is basically telling you that it can't find either file. Sounds like the `.pas` files you added to your project are referencing that unit, and although Indy is pre-installed in the IDE, maybe it is not referenced in your project, so the compiler is trying to find Indy's source files instead.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response. I will investigate further, The project itself does not include any Indy components, so I need to work out why the linker would be referencing an Indy Resource.

Comment: I checked further and found that the PAS file had TidBytes and TIdHashMessageDigest5.  Including a reference to IdBaseComponent.hpp into the C++ main.h file fixed the issue and it linked fine. Thanks again for your detailed and quick response, save me lots of searching.

Comment: Those types belong to Indy 10, they are defined in its IndySystem and IndyProtocols packages, respectively. It is not enough to just `#include` Indy's header files, you need to also link to Indy's library, or its source code. Modern C++Builder versions have a built-in MD5 implementation in the [`System::Hash::THashMD5`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Hash.THashMD5) class, if you want to update the `.pas` file to break its dependency on Indy (if those are the only Indy types it uses).

Comment: Thanks, I found some components were not correctly installed. I did a check to ensure the Indy paths and libraries were correctly defined and I did a re-install of the Jedi components and made sure the Library path and Include path were correct for Jedi.  All seems to be working fine, your initial pointing to the Indy components was most helpful.